# Cherokee skips fastcgi-mono-server4 running asp.net MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, fastcgi, cherokee

My problem is that when I run an API with cherokee and mono, cherokee skips the fastcgi-mono-server and says 404 not found, instead of returning the data from mono-server.

I followed this tutorial of cherokee to run asp.net under mono:
http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_mono.html

And I launch the fastcgi-mono-server4 with the next command from the console:

sudo fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/myapplication/:/srv/www/htdocs/myapplication/,/test/:/srv/www/htdocs/test/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /stopable=TRUE /filename=/temp/cherokee-mono.socket /logfile=/home/aamarber/mono-server4.log

When I put this in the browser: localhost/myapplication it says HTTP 500 The value for the name controller must be a non-empty string; that's OK, because myapplication is an api.

But if I put localhost/myapplication/websites/getwebsites it says the 404 error.

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: API means asmx base services, REST implementation, etc? Can you provide more details?

Comment: It's an ASP MVC Controller, well, lots of them, but if with your help I can see only one working, the others will fall! :D